# Can we use yii1 extensions in yii2

Tags: php, yii-extensions, yii2

I want to use an auth extension in yii2.
I found the same in yii1: http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/auth/

Can I use this extension in yii2?

Be glad to any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Found this as a useful [link](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-extensions.html). I could make some Yii 1.0 extensions work using this.